# How to do this delimiter?

Tags: java, string, text-parsing

I have this String:

> 1945:New York University:70:Ohio State:65

I want to use a Scanner to read it and ignore the `':'`, `70`, and `65`, which are the score fields. But I want it to read the year. I know how to set the delimiter to discard all the numbers and the `':'`, but I don't know how to make it discard only certain numbers. Is what I'm talking about actually possible to do?

Comment: If you're sure that the first 4 characters is the required year, why not just extract that alone using `String.substring(0, 4)`?

Comment: Split `:` character, loop through it and ignore which is not number

Comment: You want to read year, university and state only am I right?

Comment: Yes, I know I can do it in other ways. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it using a delimiter for Scanner.

Comment: couldn't you just delimit on ':' and ignore index 2 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer, reposted sans humor

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1945:New York University:70:Ohio State:65");
scanner.useDelimiter(":(\\d\\d:?)?");

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("1945:New York University:70:Ohio State:65");
    sc.useDelimiter(":\\d+:|:\\d+$|:");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
```

output

```
1945
New York University
Ohio State
```